# Pushing View from UITableView Problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Basically, what I want is to be able to press a record in a table, and have it push to another view.

To do this, I created a nib file and a UIViewController subclass (for the "pushed" view). I set the nib file's "File Owner" to be the controller I created. ***EDIT***: I also then set the "view" field of the controller to be the View. Then, in the view controller of the table that will push that view, I set the didSelectRowIndexAtPath: method to include the following:

`SearchTableController *vc = [[SearchTableController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchTable" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    [vc release];`

(where "SearchTableController" is the name of the UIViewController subclass and "SearchTable" is the name of the nib file)

However, when I run this code and click on the record, nothing happens- the app doesn't crash, but the view doesn't get pushed. The code is getting run, because it works when I NSLog(), but it doesn't seem to be pushing the view.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close, but did you tie the view in the nib file to the view field of the view controller?

[image]

EDIT: So the view is connected, and your code looks just fine. I just pulled a piece of my own code:

`// show theme settings
ThemeController * theme = [[[ThemeController alloc] 
                            initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:theme animated:YES];`

Have you checked if `self.navigationController` is non-nil?

Couple of things I'd try at this point:

- just hard-code the view to come up as the root view, verify it works
- put a couple of NSLogs in the viewWillLoad, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear in the client view controller

Best of luck.

Comment: If it helps, the code that pushes the view is in the controller class of a UITableView that is in another view... so maybe that might be the issue.

Comment: Fixed- I just realized that I wasn't working with a UINavigationController, just a UIView :)